# WCF Cross Domain Using Jsonp Error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

Tags: jquery, .net, wcf, rest, jsonp

I am trying to call webservice over cross domain using jQuery.

Here is my code to call service

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            async: false,
            contentType: "application/json",
            url: "http://localhost:52136/Service1.svc/Helloworld?callback=func_callbk",
            dataType: "jsonp",
            success: function (data) {
                alert('sucesss')
                alert(data.d);
            },
            error: function (data) {
                alert(data);
            }
        });
    });

    func_callback = function (data) {
        alert(data.data.people[0].id);
    }
```

I am returning simple string from the service.

```
public string HelloWorld()
{
    return "Hello World";
}
```

Service is called from, but I am getting error

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

in console window of Chrome.

I am getting this  string while calling service from the browse:

```
{"HelloWorldResult":"Hello World"}
```

Please let me know where am I going wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @DipeshParmar Semicolon is not required in javascript, only recommended.

Comment: Thanks @DipeshParmar, but it didn't solve the issue.

Comment: You seem to be requesting jsonp (padded json) but return a string from the server. Could you show the full output the server gives please?
Do you get the error upon initializing of the javascript or after the ajax call have been made?

Comment: With jsonp, What you should see is `somefunction({"HelloWorldResult":"Hello World"});` . Set `CrossDomainScriptAccessEnabled`

Comment: Hello @Jite
Server method is called and gives output **{"HelloWorldResult":"Hello World"}**

Comment: What happens if you remove the dataType: "jsonp", property? The response is just JSON not padded JSON.

Comment: jsonp requires callback function. where is it ?

Comment: If I change datatype to JSON, server method is not called at all and getting error **405 (Method Not Allowed)**

Comment: If it have to be jsonp, you should add a callback function (as Patel asks about above). Check the jquery documentation.

Comment: I have added callback function and edited question, but getting the same error.

Answer (score 2):

Your WCF server should be configured to enable `jsonp` with `CrossDomainScriptAccessEnabled`

Here is a simple working example

**Server:**

```
Task.Run(() =>
{
    var uri = new Uri("http://0.0.0.0/test");
    var type = typeof(TestService);
    WebServiceHost host = new WebServiceHost(type, uri);
    WebHttpBinding binding = new WebHttpBinding();
    binding.CrossDomainScriptAccessEnabled = true;
    host.AddServiceEndpoint(type, binding, uri);


    host.Open();

});

[ServiceContract]
public class TestService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    public string Hello()
    {
        return "Hello World";
    }
}
```

And this is the javascript code

```
<html>
<body>
<script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js'></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        async: false,
        contentType: "application/json",
        url: "http://localhost/test/hello",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
        },
        error: function (data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    });
});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Now you can test it from your browser

```
http://localhost/test/hello
```

and

```
http://localhost/test/hello?callback=myfunc
```