# Set html textBox value from Webmethod

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a ajax method which is passing data between pages ...I need to set one html textbox value at retrieving end ..

I tried to do it ...it gives error :

> ```
>          //Err : cant set static value to non static member
> ```

I am only seeing examples of returning static string ...But no other examples

this is my ajax method :

```
 $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: "WebForm1.aspx/GetData",
                data: JSON.stringify({ cc: cc }),
                dataType: "json",
                async: false,
                success: function () {


            },
            });
```

this is webmethod at recieving end :

```
[WebMethod]
        [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
        public static void GetData(tbl1 cc)
        {
         //Getting data in cc
         //Not able to set value to textbox ..
         //Err : cant set static value to non static method
        }
```

How can I set the simple Html input textbox value from CodeBehing(WebMethod) or by at client End  ..I searched a Lot..but couldnot found the relevant solution ..More post I found is about that not able to "get data in WebMethod "One solution i was suggest to try Request.Form[] ...But it also not working ..

Some codes are complicated ..is it possible to retrieve data from WebMethod to html controls  ?

Please Suggest

Comment: `ajax` run in your browser and `GetData` is executed on your server. It think you are confused.

Comment: I need to set Html Textbox value from code behind ..Just want to know is it possible ..or any other alternative ?

Comment: I would reorganize the logic. On one side, the server methods providing data to clients, on the other side clients making request to server using ajax and updating the controls based on the results returned from servers.

Comment: I believe you are saying this might not be possible ...is there any other way around ..I just want to set one textbox using $.ajax ...either by server side code or by client side code

Comment: See the `success` parameter of ajax http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ . Your `GetData` method can return the value to be set to textBox. I mean something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18821989/wcf-cross-domain-using-jsonp-error-uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token)

Comment: i Edited my Code .I belive success function  will be on sending side ..How will it help to retrieve data ?and i also try to set textbox value inside webmethod ..it gives following Err : cant set static value to non static member

Comment: See the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18821989/wcf-cross-domain-using-jsonp-error-uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token) in my previous comment ... Server & Client codes are completely separated..

Comment: The only difference is that you should use something like `$('#mytextbox').val(data);` instead of `alert` in *success* function.

Comment: .I read your post ...i am getting a bit confused ..  $('#mytextbox').val(data);..this  code should be set in sending Page $.ajax() method ?..I did that to sending page ajax method ..It wont recognise recieving page textbox . Or it should be on the receiving page $.ajax() with "GET" Type ??