# Simple WEB API REST Project

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

What is the best way to create a simple REST API in Visual Studio 2013 using ASP.NET MVC.

I just want something with controllers and route config along with any other basic requirements for a HTTP REST API.

I don't require any Razor view engine, Javascript or HTML inclusions.

How can I create a project without all the unwanted extras, which I usually remove in the past?

Thank you.

Comment: You'll have to search for it, but there is a NuGet package which is a Web API starter kit without all the MVC website stuff (views, images, JavaScript, bundling, etc.)

Comment: You may also want to try WCF's `WebServiceHost` (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18821989/wcf-cross-domain-using-jsonp-error-uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

It's all in the template you select.

1. In the New Project dialog, select ".NET Framework 4.5" if not already selected
2. Navigate to Installed > Templates > Visual C# > Web, then "ASP.NET Web Application" and select OK.
3. On the dialog to select the project type, select "Empty", but then be sure to check "Web API" under "Add folders and core references.

Now you'll have the bare minimums created.

See: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api

Comment: How about a non-mvc? I would like to create an web api which I can host in IIS that can be accessed from anywhere on the web...

Comment: Same as above. The version numbers are updated a bit since this answer is over 2 years old, but concept is the same (you select version now in dropdown and then "ASP.NET Web Application") in latest VS2015. Select "Empty" project, then be sure "Web API" is checked. Then deploy your app to any IIS instance. If you ever want to get out of IIS and host separately, then look into OWIN.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what parts of ASP.NET you want, you could check out Nancy at https://github.com/thecodejunkie/Nancy. It can be hosted within ASP.NET and is pretty light-weight and provides a simple routing with options to plug in different view technologies (Razor, Spark, SimpleView and more).

Answer (score 2):

You can remove the MVC component if you wish, and just use Web API 2 stuff.    Add your own custom config bit:

```
        //attribute routing - lets me put any route any method in any darn file.
        //this sets you free.  I could never see doing it any other way.
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
```

So that you can create any route you wish on the fly, in any file you create as a Controller.

```
public class MyWeirdController : ApiController {
    //via REST, get object //method-route defined here as I want it
    [HttpGet] [Route("~/my/custom/route/someobject/{objectid}")]    
    public CustomObject GonnaGetCustomObject(int objectid) {

       .... use whatever 
      var obj = new CustomObject();
      obj.SetSomething = true;

     return obj
    }
}
```

You don't need MVC.    I use WebAPI2 with Linq2SQL (Entities is more of a PITA when I want simple) - but that part isn't needed either.     L2SQL entities are just faster/easier to stand up and get running with their modeling classes - but any class or whatever you want, send it.

I usually use Knockout if I want to MVVM it on the javascript side.  With KO.Mapping -- I can, with one line of code - receive that `CustomOBject` and have a JS object to work with and instantly bind to elements on the page.   The toughest part of all of this is learning Knockout.   Custom attribute writing with WebAPI2 is crazy easy and fun.

In short, WebAPI2 with custom attribute routing is all you need to stand up a REST client in any way you want.   Break out your "controllers" any way you wish with any methods/returns/types as you want.  You can make it as simple as you want, or start tossing in things like Knockout and L2SQL (or EF) to type-bind things even closer.

Answer (score -2):

I suppose the best way for your project is to use WebApi even with simple HTML page, but... jQuery and even something like Knockout.JS or Angular, this is MUST HAVE for any modern project.

Comment: What about a modern project that is a REST API with no html output/view rendering at all. Thanks.

Comment: If no view/output at all, probably this is some kind of console application? At least WebApi that's best solution for REST.