# Android - MSSQL cannot connect to database

Tags: java, android, sql-server, sql-server-2008, jdbc

I'm using android studio and I'm trying to make an hello world database program, with ms sql server with jdbc, I'm using SQL Server 2008..
I made a code and when I debug the program with brakepoint I saw that it stuck on line :

> Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");

```
String connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost";
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);
Statement s = con.createStatement();
ResultSet r = s.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM Admin");
while (r.next()) {
System.out.println(r.getString(1));
}
```

and the exception is :

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver

And yes, I imported that jar file.

Thnx in Advance :)

Comment: IMHO, android should talk to a rest (webapi) service......and not to a sql server.  you webapi would talk to the sql server.

Comment: I saw alot of tutorials that works directly ? or I'm wrong ?
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HRF8NpoFteg

Comment: Just because you can do it, doesn't mean you should do it.  I can put "read the database" code behind a button click...doesn't mean its a good idea.

Comment: aha, thnx, than can you help me with any example with webapi service ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26562918/simple-web-api-rest-project